# IronPython how to set marker type to tiles?

Tags: scatter-plot, ironpython, spotfire

I looked through the documentation [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.6.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_ScatterPlot.htm) and found the MarkerClass, but can't figure out how to set it to be  Tile (enum value 2). Here is what I've tried so far:

```
chart.MarkerClass = MarkerClass(2)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
chart.MarkerClass = MarkerClass().Tile
```